# Grant access to Terraformer role only when called through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We use Terraform with AWS. The AWS provider uses role assumption to execute `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`. For example:

```
provider "aws" {
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Terraformer"
  }
}
```

Any identity that runs `terraform` therefore needs permission to assume the `Terraformer` role. Is it possible to limit direct assumption of this role outside the context of Terraform?

For example, with CloudFormation, you can specify the [`aws:CalledVia` policy condition key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-calledvia). This will restrict access to actions *unless* those actions are taken through CloudFormation.

Is there any way to replicate something like this with Terraform?

Comment: CalledVia works with CF because it's an AWS service running in AWS. WIth TF running on a remote machine, AWS has no way to know what calling process is making the API calls. I think the closest you'll get is restricting to the http user agent used by TF. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-useragent

Comment: Also of note, systems like Terraform Enterprise, Scalr, and Atlantis allow you to apply TF in a way that you do no need to provide your TF developers with access to the role because apply happens remotely.

Comment: Yes you likely want to execute TF in automation based on these requirements.